# Universal Layout for all tablets

Tags: android, layout

I am doing project at home that involves 4 buttons in the left and 4 buttons in the right with a size 100 by 100dp. I used absolute layout so that it sits in the required place correctly by giving the x and y value.

This just works fine with 7" tablet with resolution 800*440.. If I get apk installed on Samsung Galaxy Tab or any other resolution other than 800*440 The button are placed randomly or in different smaller.

How do I fix this? Using Relative layout or different layout I can't enter the button size value? I want the button to be in specific size.

Can somebody help me out with this issue? How to have my button placed in the same place for any tablet with any resolution.

Awaiting your response!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use relative layout and fix the size of your button. It is not a problem. Relative layouts are best to provide flexibility.

Comment: How do I put the fixed size of the button. If I put the  width and length of the button say 100 by 100 then doesn't show up correctly in relative layout like the absolute layout - the button overlaps or goes of the screen? BTW: Is the value of relative layout and absolute layout going to be same or does it differ because the same value of what I had in absolute layout?

Comment: Post code of your layout I will try to fix it for you...

Comment: Actually the width will be in dp so it will vary according to devices. It is not working in your case because relative layout works according to the relation with other views. If you move any of the view then it will re-arrange all other views which are in relation of that views.

Comment: any good solution for this? I am still stuck with this problem? I want to have 4 buttons each in left and right side of the screen (vertically)... i.e row wise 4 buttons each side. in the middle of the screen it is plain. It is perfect only for one tablet but If I use it on different tablet that has different resolution I have a problem? Any help would be appreciated? Thanks!

Comment: Actually i have shifted to java swing currently but i have posted some code for you try this and tell me if still you are facing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example this below layout will always having buttons at center if any problem you are facing then you can ask i will try to help you..

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button 1" android:width="100dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button 2" android:width="100dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button 3" android:width="100dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button 4" android:height="50dp" android:width="100dp"/>
```